# Warning: Missing argument 4 for Page::generate(),

Tags: php

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for Page::generate(), called in /home//index.php on line 44 and defined in /home//core/structure.php on line 59

Строки :

```
index.php 44: 
Page::Generate(Route::start($page, $_GET['mode'], '', '0'));

structure.php 59: 
static function generate($content, $action = "index", $case, $id)
```

Comment: Михаил, а вот вы как сами бы перевели сообщение `Missing argument 4 for Page::generate()` ? ................и почему то `4`, то `3`?

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 3 for Page::generate(), called in /home//index.php on line 44 and defined in /home//core/structure.php on line 59

Warning: Missing argument 4 for Page::generate(), called in /home//index.php on line 44 and defined in /home//core/structure.php on line 59    Там две ошибки сразу. Сам сайт грузится,а эти ошибки вверху.

Comment: Не надо копировать еще раз ошибку в комментарий........ Я спросил вас `вы как сами бы перевели сообщение  Missing argument 3 for Page::generate()` и `Missing argument 4 for Page::generate()` ?

Comment: и почему то 4, то 3?  - Я ответил.   Перевел бы я так: Отсутствие аргумента 3,4 для страницы:: Генерировать()

Comment: Так..... и что же вам не ясно в словах `Отсутствие аргумента 3,4` ?  (Только скорее `Отсутствует`)

Comment: Я не кодер,я только начинаю учится,допустим я понял что что-то отсутствует,но я не знаю как это исправить)

Comment: Попробую намекнуть. У вас есть метод `static function generate` который **принимает 4-ре аргумента**. ....сколько параметров у вас передано в  `Page::Generate` на 44 строке?  .........(кстати почему `Generate` с большой буквы?)

Comment: То есть,мне надо взять те параметры из Page::Generate и вписать их в static function?

Comment: @Михаил никто кроме вас не знает что вообще делают методы `Page::Generate` и `Route::start`, ровно как и никто не знает вашей задачи. Поэтому вам никто не скажет, как конкретно исправлять эту ошибку.

Comment: @Михаил просто сделайте так, чтобы число формальных и фактических параметров совпадало.

Comment: Хотите помощи добавте объявление функции `Route::start`.

Comment: А за обязательные аргументы функции, идущие **после** необязательных, надо бить по рукам.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Вообще, это публичный расстрел :)

Answer (score 3):

```
//index.php 44: 
Page::Generate(
    Route::start($page, $_GET['mode'], '', '0')
);

//structure.php 59: 
static function generate(
    $content,
    $action = "index",
    $case,
    $id
)
```

А теперь, считаем элементы которые имеют отступы.

В первом случаее это **1**

Во втором **4**

Поэтому вам и намекают нужно что бы и в первом было **4.**

**PS:**

Похоже, что `Route::start(` лишний. Но я могу ошибаться так как не знаю код. А может скобка не там закрыта

```
//index.php 44: 
Page::Generate(
    Route::start($page),
    $_GET['mode'],
    '',
    '0'
);
```

или

```
//index.php 44: 
Page::Generate(
    Route::start($page, $_GET['mode']),
    '',
    '0'
);
```

**PPS:**

Кстати, не знаю кто писал метод

`static function generate($content, $action = "index", $case, $id)` .

Но, необязательные параметры, надо передовать в конце функции.

`static function generate($content, $case, $id, $action = "index")` .

Правда не знаю насколько проблеммно это поменять будет

Comment: не `Route::start(` лишний скорее всего, а просто `Route::start` принимает на самом деле один параметр и скобочка закрывающая не там, как написали в другом ответе..... но это знает лишь один ТС, из чего реально состоят у него методы.......хотя странно наблюдать человека, который пишет методы и классы свои но не может прочитать ошибку о четырех аргументах и её исправить))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Возможно. Там еще просто палигон для ошибок с необязательным параметром по середине :).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Великая сила копипасты!!! :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `хотя странно наблюдать человека, который пишет методы и классы`  В данном случае похоже что класс используется для групировки функций т.е. 100% эквивалент `function Route_start` поэтому с тем что автор пишет классы я не согласен.

Comment: значит ему в начале надо идти изучать самые присамые основы, а потом, через годок например начинать что-то делать

Comment: Ничего не получилось.

Comment: @Михаил Не переживайте, это может случиться с каждым. Придется идти сложным путем, сначала учиться. Так же всегда можно заплатить знающему человеку что бы поправил.

Comment: @Михаил ПС: У вас 2 правильных ответа и куча хороших советов. Значит, не зря время потрачено!

Answer (score 0):

Наверное ошибка вам не понятна, потому что идёт вложенный вызов методов, и ошибочно может показаться (если глаза замылились), что 4 параметра отправлено.

Comment: Помоги человеку, покажи наглядно ему где что не так)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так не интересно ))

Comment: Не понять мне этого :с

Comment: @Михаил ключевые слова ответа: generate, start

Comment: @ZhandosMan Вот хоть убей,но я не понял :D Поправь лучше строки которые я скинул и все,пожалуйста :D

Comment: @Михаил я бы вам настоятельно порекомендовал изучить в начале самые самые основы программирования и языка программирования (пара книжек, пара видео уроков, посмотреть мануалы), а потом что-то средне или сложное пилить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Единственная ошибка которая вышла,а так все правильно все,думал хоть где-то помогут)

Comment: @Михаил вам столько уже сказали, что толще этих намеков просто не может быть.. И это показывает, что у вас капитально не хватает банальных основ из основ всея программирования.  Поэтому кажется вы сейчас не тем заняты.